# Passing and handling of varibles to a function with AJAX in MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having trouble passing a variable into a function in my view. I'm fairly new to MVC and not sure how I save and pass information.

```
@model Models.Schedule.SheduleModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div>
    <div class="tableRow">
        <p>Make a schedule reminder.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tableRow tableRowHeading">
        <div class="row" style="width: 210px">Name</div>
        <div class="row" style="width: 210px">Number</div>
    </div>

    @foreach (var shedule in Model.ScheduleList)
    {
        <div class="tableRow">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateSchedule", "Schedule", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="cell" style="width: 210px">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(model => schedule.Id)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => schedule.Name, new { @class = "inputFieldText" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => schedule.Name)
                </div>
                <div class="cell" style="width: 210px">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => agent.ContactNumber, new { @class = "inputFieldText" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => agent.ContactNumber)
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                    <button name="Update" type="submit" value="Update" class="button" title="Update details">
                        <span class="text">Update</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="cell">
                    <button class="button" type="button" onclick="deleteFromSchedule();" value="Delete">
                        <span class="text">Delete</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    }
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script>
    function deleteFromSchedule() {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: urlBase + 'Schedule/UpdateSchedule/' + Id,
                    data:
                    {
                        Id: Id
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        var errorMessage = 'Error occurred while sending message';
                        console.log(errorMessage);
                    }
                });
    }
    }
</script>
```

I'm trying to pass the schedule Id in HiddenFor into the delete function but everything I try doesn't work, i'm also curious on how to handle the information gotten from the text box in a later unwritten div, I'd like to produce text on the screen saying

User @Model.Name and number @Model.Number will be notified of schedule change but I keep displaying blank spaces. an I use the form I'm creating for this information, what would the syntax be?. My method in the schedule controller is very straight forward.

```
[HttpPost]
    public void UpdateSchedule(int Id)
    {
    ////do stuff here
    }
```

Comment: You have many issues in your code. **1)** In your razor code use a plain old `for` loop so your controls can have different names and ids. Do not use `foreach` because you will end up with multiple html controls all having the same names. **2)** Once you do 1, in the `onclick` of the button, pass the `scheduleId` to the function. Make sure each button is generated for the row in the for loop. **3)** In your js fuction make sure you it is taking one argument. **4)** If you do not make these changes, none of your validations work and many other things will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to add your id from the schedule into the inline function call (using razor), and add an `id` param into your javascript delete function:

```
<div class="cell">
    <button class="button" type="button" onclick="deleteFromSchedule(@schedule.Id);" value="Delete">
        <span class="text">Delete</span>
    </button>
</div>


<script>
    function deleteFromSchedule(id) {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: urlBase + 'Schedule/UpdateSchedule/' + id,
                    data:
                    {
                        Id: id
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        var errorMessage = 'Error occurred while sending message';
                        console.log(errorMessage);
                    }
                });
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok cheers, and I assume I could use these values aswell in my <p> tag like [at-sign]schedule.Id and [at-sign]schedule.Name

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's the beauty of razor syntax.

Comment: Adding the `id` twice is not necessary (to the url and as `data`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, you are [probably] right. But that is dependent upon how routing is set up in the routing config. So I refrain from suggesting a change to that.